# Running a nested loop simultaneously

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I've written a nested `for`-loop but the problem is that I want loop 2 & 3 to run simultaneously such that when `x=1`, `y=1` when `x=4`, `y=2` , when `x=7,`y=3` and so on but have no idea how. I've given my code below:

```
for i=2:25
  for x=1:3:60
     for y=1:20
       Dte(i,y)=sqrt(dcc(x,1) + dcc(x+1,1).*.(Er(i-1,y)).^2 + dcc(x+2,1).* Dte(i-1,y).^2);
     end
  end
end
```

I've tried to read up on par for loop but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: In the above code, `x` never equals to be `3` or `6`.

Comment: @Usama, Yes, i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to replace the two inner most nested loops with only one loop.

You can simply do:

```
for i=2:25
  for y=1:20
    x = (y - 1) * 3 + 1;
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean Logeart! That looks quite simple but wouldn't that create problems for the first iteration? because when y=1, I want x to be equal to 1 too..